# iOS ACEDrawingView can't set RGB colour, only default UIColor value

Tags: ios, cocoa, uicolor

I'm playing around with this `ACEDrawingView` code: https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView

I'm trying to set the pen color using RGB values, but it crashes every time I try to draw with the pen set to a custom RGB value. However, it works completely fine when it's set to any of the default `UIColor` settings.

I'm pretty sure I'm setting the `UIColor` up correctly, I've done it a bunch of other times with no problem, using code something like:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

No idea what's going on, I'm a total noob to iOS programming.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

In ACEDrawingView.h

change 
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor *lineColor;

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *lineColor;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the fix. I've updated the code on github

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the top of the file under your `#import` statements and you can use HEX values:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue, alphaValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:alphaValue]
```

And then wherever you'd like to use RGB colors, implement the following:

For Red (FF0000) : `UIColorFromRGB(0xFF0000, 1.0)`